# Почему данные не передаются в шаблон?

Tags: php

В чем может быть причина и что я не так делаю?

```
extract($result_array);//id1 = значение

ViewController::loadFile('admin');
// $templateFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/View/'.$nameFile.'.php';
```

Код шаблона:

```
<td><?=$id1?></td>
```

Comment: Какой фреймворк?

Comment: Потому что данные нужно передавать во view вместе с шаблоном и распаковывать в методе, который выводит/выполняет шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо тебе Добрый человек! Да, теперь передаются. А где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Нет, это не фреймворк, а "сапмопись", без шаблонизаторов(twig, smarty и тд) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо, @Visman.
Переделал вот так:

```
 ViewController::loadFile('admin', $result_array);
```

Метод `LoadFile`:

```
public static function loadFile($nameFile,$array_date=[])
{
    $templateFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/View/'.$nameFile.'.php';


    if (is_file($templateFile)){
        if(!empty($array_date)) {
            extract($array_date);
            require $templateFile;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception(
            sprintf('View file $s does not exist',$templateFile)
        );
    }
}
```

Все переменные теперь в шаблоне.